# Bisectional Search: In case of a tie, return lower value

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops

I'm trying to study for midterms and am struggling with this problem. The question is this:

> Find the integer exponent such that `base**exponent` is closest to `num`.
>   Note that the `base**exponent` may be either greater or smaller than `num`.
>   In case of a tie, return the smaller value.
>   I've gotten everything except how to return the smaller value in case of a tie.

This is my code and the function `closest_power(3,12)`keeps going between the exponents 3, and 2 (the correct code will return 2). Any help is much appreciated

```
def closest_power(base, num):
    exponential = base+num/2
    increment = 1
    while  abs(num-base**exponential) >= 0.01:
        print ("Exp: {}, Our number = {}, correct number: {}".format(exponential,base**exponential, num))
        if num > (num-base**exponential-2) and num <  (num-base**exponential):
            return expontential-1

        if base**exponential > num:
            exponential -= 1

        else:
            exponential += 1


    return exponential

print(closest_power(3,12))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your test for whether `num` is between two exponents is incorrect, it should be

```
num > base**(exponential-1) and num < base**exponential
```

which can also be written as

```
base**(exponential-1) < num < base**exponential
```

Also you have a typo,

```
return expontential-1
```

should be

```
return exponential-1
```

and you should set the starting value as

```
exponential = (base + num) // 2
```

to ensure it is an integer, but it would be even more efficient to set it to:

```
exponential = num // base
```

In total:

```
def closest_power(base, num):
    exponential = num // base
    increment = 1
    while  abs(num-base**exponential) >= 0.01:
        print ("Exp: {}, Our number = {}, correct number: {}".format(exponential,base**exponential, num))
        if base**(exponential-1) < num < base**exponential:
            return exponential-1

        if base**exponential > num:
            exponential -= 1

        else:
            exponential += 1


    return exponential

print(closest_power(3,12))
```

Output:

```
Exp: 4, Our number = 81, correct number: 12
Exp: 3, Our number = 27, correct number: 12
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather simplify your problem using log.

Your question is 3**x = 12. Find x?

Apply log

x*log3 = log12

x = log12/log3

Using this approach:

```
def exp(x,y):
   return(int(log(y)/log(x)))
```

Comment: This was smooth

Comment: `int(log_base(num))` is not necessarily the closest answer. For example, if num=15 and base=4, then your function returns 1, but the right answer is 2. However, you can calculate `int(log_base(num))` and `int(log_base(num))+1` and choose the best match,